# Disable login animation in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, login, animation

I am running Mac OS X Lion in VMWare Workstation 8. The graphics performance is not stellar, so most of the animations built into the OS are a bit choppy. I have already disabled the window animations, but would also like to disable the desktop "zoom" effect that occurs when you log in. Is this possible?

You can see this animation [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=y4Y80hEQjqE#t=48s).